# Save certificate thumbprint as a variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, awk, formatting

Powershell newblart here. I'm trying to save a thumbprint from a specific certificate as a variable for use later in a script. I've gotten far! but not far enough. I am able to filter the certificates by the cert template, so I've narrowed down to a single thumbprint displayed, but there is other output that is blocking me. I'm trying to use the split method (erroneously) to start chopping up the output. Here's what I have so far:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | ? {$_.Extensions | ? {$_.oid.friendlyname -match "Template" -and $_.Format(0) -match "Kerberos Authentication"}}


    Directory: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\my


Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
8635AF13624FEA042664BCDD0EC4661C7E07FA0F
```

What i need is just the thumbprint, not all the other output. 
I'm trying to use split, but it looks like this output is not a string. This is there error i get with split. (here im just trying to split on a spave to see where that leads me, space may likely be the wrong thing to try and split on):

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | ? {$_.Extensions | ? {$_.oid.friendlyname -match "Template" -and $_.Format(0) -match "Kerberos Authentication"}} | %{ $_.Split(' ')[1]; }
Method invocation failed because [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2] doesn't contain a method named 'Split'.
At line:1 char:157
+ ... cation"}} | %{ $_.Split(' ')[1]; }
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Any help would be much appropriated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of your first statement is an object, with a `Thumbprint` property which is why it displays that way. But that table format is for display purposes only. You wouldn't act on that output generally. Instead you would want to just get the property. So you could:

#### Wrap the whole statement in parentheses and use dot `.` like this:

```
(Get-ChildItem ...etc).Thumbprint
```

#### Use `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem ...etc | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Thumbprint
```

#### Assign to a variable first and do either of the above:

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem ...etc

$cert.Thumbprint
$cert | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Thumbprint
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

First, determine the thumbprint of the certificate you want to assign to a variable, then use this syntax:

For Current User certificate store:

```
$MyCert = $(Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\my | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq '[THUMBPRINT]'})
```

For Local Machine certificate store:

```
$MyCert = $(Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq '[THUMBPRINT]'})
```